# If $g(x):=f(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous, is $f$ a constant (assuming it's periodic)?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, periodic-functions

I know that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and periodic. How can I prove that $f$ is a constant whenever $g(x):=f(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Try plotting $f(x^2)$ for various periodic $f$. Notice what happens - the period gets continually smaller. Can you see why this would exclude uniform continuity if $f$ isn't constant?

Comment: I know that every periodic function is uniformly continuous and I tried to apply the definition of uniform continuity with the function $f$ that is also periodic ($f(x+T)=f(x)$) but I wasn't able to go on with $f(x^2)$. I was thinking about the increment of the derivative to prove that $f$ is constant but I don't know how to formalize that.

Comment: My opinion is f=sinx satisfy above conditions but not constant, isn't it?

Comment: @user128766 $\sin x^2$ isn't uniformly continuous

Comment: @M99: Not _every_ periodic function is uniformly continuous -- for  example a sawtooth curve is periodic but _not_ uniformly continuous.(Every _continuous_ periodic function is uniformly contrinuous, though).

Comment: Yes, sorry, obviously every continuous periodic function is uniformly continuous. I forgot to say that because it is in the hypothesis.

Comment: @M99: If you add more of your work to the question or at least some other [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), you might get more complete answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Suppose $f$ is *not* constant (but still periodic, say, with period $p$). This means that there are $a$ and $b$ with $f(a)\ne f(b)$.

Now we're looking to prove that $g$ cannot be uniformly continuous.

In the definition of uniform continuity, set $\varepsilon = \frac12 |f(a)-f(b)|$. Can you see why there can be no positive $\delta$ that works?

Comment: Out of curiosity -- why downvoting?

Comment: @ClementC. did I downvoted anything?

Comment: @Clement: My working assumption is that someone objects to the question getting any answer because it is just a verbatim homework problem submitted with any work by the OP. That's a position I have some sympathy for -- and for the same reason I deliberately omitted enough that the OP cannot really complete the proof unless he actually does understand how uniform continuity works, as well as understands what composing with $x^2$ does.

Comment: @M99 Not you -- yet someone did (which puzzles me, as this appears to be quite a good hint). After seeing Henning Makholm's comment, however, I understand the position (if this is indeed the correct interpretation).

Comment: @M99: No, _you_ didn't downvote -- you can't even do that until you have 150 rep. But _someone_ did.

Comment: @Clement: I suspect it was just an ordinary user clicking with his ordinary mouse.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I assume you are correct. I deleted my answer 6 seconds after posting, when I realized that you had been downvoted and I looked back and saw that the question was a PSQ.  If more context is added, I may undelete my answer. (+1 BTW)

Comment: This conversation inspired me to downvote the question, not the answer. I don't believe the asker has an interest beyond a cheap A.

Comment: I tried in this way: we can assume that $f$ has period equals to 1 (if the period is T we can come back to the case 1 choosing h(x)=f(Tx) whose period is 1); if we can prove that $h(x)$ is constant then $f(x)=h(x/T)$ will be constant, too. We assume that $f(x)$, whose period is 1, is such that $f(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous, hence, fixed $\epsilon$, we know that $|f((x+t)^2)-f(x^2)| < \epsilon$ if $|t|<\delta$. 
We choose $x=n$ and we get $|f(n^2 + 2nt + t^2)-f(n^2)|<\epsilon$ with $|t|<\delta$. Since $f$ is periodic $|f(2nt+t^2)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for $|t|<\delta$.

Comment: The function $2nt+t^2$ that describe the abscissae where we compute $f$ is a non decreasing function and is continuous for $|t|<\delta$,then it reaches every value between $-2n\delta + \delta^2$ and $2n\delta+\delta^2$, that is it catches every value of an interval $I$ of amplitude $4n\delta$.If $n$ is big enough,it will be $4n\delta>1$ and $f$, periodic with period 1, assumes all the values in $I$.Then $\sup_{s \in [0.1]} |f(s)-f(0)|<\epsilon$.Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $f$ is constant.P.s.: maybe everything is wrong but I tried!thank you for your trust,your conversation is disheartening!